# Unable to invoke pjax programmatically

Tags: ajax, jquery, pjax

Im trying to programmatic invoke pjax/ajax to change to another page.

I call this method somwhere inside the '#pjax-container':

```
  pjax.pjax({url: $url, container: '#pjax-container'});
```

I then get this error:

```
uncaught exception: cant get selector for pjax container!
```

What is wrong here? I guess I could make a hidden link, change its html to have it pointing at $url and perform a click, but this method should be used just for this situation I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke a PJAX page load programmatically by calling the pjax.invoke() method

```
pjax.invoke({url:'page1.php', 'container': 'content'});
```

or

```
pjax.invoke('page1.php', 'content');
```